# Iterating the JSON Array in Angular5 with the help of ngFor

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using Angular5 for building a project. I am stuck in `*ngFor`. 
I have a model class as below:

```
export class FetchApi {
  value: Array<String>;
  api_status: string;
  api_version: string;
  data: Array<String>;

}
```

My component.ts is receiving the data from service, which is calling an API and fetching the data.

My service code is:

```
public getUsers() { 
    console.log("heyyy"+this.fetchUrl);
    return this.http.get <FetchApi[]> (this.fetchUrl); }
```

My component code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
     const scope = this;
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.fetchApi = of(data);
        console.log(this.fetchApi)
        //this.fetchApi = data;
      });
  };
```

My JSON that the API is returning is like this:

`{
    "api_status": "200",
    "api_version": "1.0",
    "data": {
        "featured": [{
            "id": 1,
            "vid": "",
            "uid": ,
            "title": "",
            "description": ""
        }]
    }
}`

I want to render the response on my HTML page with the help of `<tr *ngFor="let fetch-api of fetchApi ">` , however, getting an error:

`FetchApiComponent.html:22 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:3121)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:8941)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10209)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10171)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10804)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10764)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FetchApiComponent.html:22)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10756)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10394)`

Please let me know what I am doing wrong as I am new to Angular5. How can I get my JSON array on my HTML page.

Answer (score 3):

You should do in your html like this to handle error in html

```
  <tr *ngFor="let fetch-api of fetchApi?.data?.featured">
```

In your typescript like :

```
this.userService.getUsers()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.fetchApi = data;
    console.log(this.fetchApi)
    //this.fetchApi = data;
  });
```

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: @N Sharma try to replace code  `of(data) ` to  `data` only because it return observable.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```html
<tr *ngFor="let fetchApi of fetchApi.data.featured">
```

As well as For/loop should execute in array and fetchApi is **object**

And then you can show you'r array's json like below

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let fetchApi of fetchApi.data.featured">
      <td>{{fetchApi | json}}</td>
    </tr>
```

And for printing Id do like below

```html
        <tr *ngFor="let fetchApi of fetchApi.data.featured">
          <td>{{fetchApi.id}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I did this and now I am getting an another error : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FetchApiComponent.html:22)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10756)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10394)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10336)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10159)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10394)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10357)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10154)
    at callViewAction (core.js:103)`

Comment: What do you see in you'r console after **console.log(this.fetchApi)** in OnInit function ?

Comment: I am getting the JSON

Comment: I know you get the json , What is it's content , paste it here

Comment: `Observable {_isScalar: true, _subscribe: ƒ, value: {…}}
value
:
api_status
:
"200"
api_version
:
"1.0"
data
:
featured
:
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
latest
:
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
top
:
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
_isScalar
:
true
_subscribe
:
ƒ (subscriber)
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: I did this : `<tr *ngFor="let fetch-api of fetchApi?.data?.featured">` and now there are no errors however, I am not able to fetch the value of `id` here. `<tr *ngFor="let fetch-api of fetchApi?.data?.featured">
    <td ></td>
   <td>{{fetch-api.id | json}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   
  </tr> `

Comment: I think you are not getting true response from you'r server, and Try to remove [] from **FetchApi[]** in  **return this.http.get <FetchApi[]> (this.fetchUrl); }**

Comment: **fetchApi?.data?.featured** is not good idea , it just hide errors. paste {{fetchApi | json}} in you'r html code and paste whatever you see in screen in here.

Comment: I have removed `[]` and I have removed `fetchApi?.data?.featured` also. But still getting the same error: `FetchApiComponent.html:22 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FetchApiComponent.html:22)`

Comment: I did like this: `<tr *ngFor="let fetch-api of fetchApi.value.data.featured">
    <td ></td>
   <td> {{fetchApi | json}} </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> ` and now getting the full JSON on page but with an error `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` on console and when I am trying to fetch the `id` then it is showing me a blank page with the same error on console.

Comment: No , just type {{fetchApi | json}} in html , and paste the result

Comment: remove of() from this.fetchApi = of(data);

Comment: If I am removing `of` then I am getting two errors `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` and `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` and I am not getting the JSON on page. I did `{{fetchApi | json}}` also.  Blank page is showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172830/discussion-between-arash-and-n-sharma).